# Channel capacity for large errors on binary symmetric channels

Tags: information-theory

The channel capacity of a binary symmetric channel is

$$ C = 1 + p \log p + (1-p) \log (1-p), $$

Where $p$ is the probability of error in transmission between Alice and Bob.

I have noticed that the capacity is $1$ when $p=1$. It is easy to see why this is the case from the above equation but I don't understand physically why this is the case. If there was 100% error on the channel, surely everything Bob receives is completely wrong and therefore the capacity to send messages is zero. Is it because if we had 100% error on the channel, Bob receives an inverted message w.r.t. Alice's and therefore it still contains all the information? All 0's became 1's and vice versa, so all Bob has to do is flip them all to return the original message, much like sending the negative instead of the photo?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly, if the error is $100\%$ every message sent by Alice is completely "flipped" by the channel, hence Bob gets the full information in it. The channel capacity is minimal at $p=\frac{1}{2}$ since every bit sent might be flipped or not with equal probability.

Comment: @Matt0410 The key here is to understand that *both* sender and receiver are aware of $p$. A probability $p=1$ indeed corresponds to an "100%" error, however, as both communicating nodes are aware that the channel "flips" the input bits, they can achieve reliable communication as if no (random) error is introduced during transmission (simply by the receiver "flipping" the incoming bits).